# MapReduce doesn't produce an output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I want to execute a simple MapReduce on textfile but it doesn't an output. This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
  }
 }
}

  public static class IntSumReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum) ;
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

I receive this errors during jar file execution:

```
17/05/07 23:10:53 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local973452829_0001
java.lang.Exception:     org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/hadoop/tmp%20/mapred/local/localRunner/hduser/jobcache/job_local973452829_0001/attempt_local973452829_0001_m_000000_0/output/file.out.index
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:193)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.openFSDataInputStream(SecureIOUtils.java:156)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.copyMapOutput(LocalFetcher.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.doCopy(LocalFetcher.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.run(LocalFetcher
```

What's the problem in my code? I'm under ubuntu 14.04 with hadoop 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a part of your error:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/hadoop/tmp%20/mapred/local/localRunner/hduser/jobcache/job_local973452829_0001/attempt_local973452829_0001_m_000000_0/output/file.out.index`

I'm guessing it's a problem with the configuration property `hadoop.tmp.dir` in your `core-site.xml` because Hadoop is unable to store the temporary output files (from Mapper) to your disk.

You can remove that property so that hadoop creates it's own temporary directory to store the intermediate output or set it to some directory with appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

try to write  hdfs commands like these

hadoop jar (jar file name) (input name) (output name)

or did you check the before to export your (jar file) did you take any warnings ?