# Hadoop: Start of Reduce phase: FileNotFoundException output/file.out.index does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to get Hadoop 3.1.0 to run on a Windows 10 system.

The exception I'm receiving is:

```
2019-11-19 14:49:13,310 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2019-11-19 14:49:13,325 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
2019-11-19 14:49:13,435 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1214244919_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:559)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:377)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:347)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-king%20lui/mapred/local/localRunner/king%20lui/jobcache/job_local1214244919_0001/attempt_local1214244919_0001_m_000001_0/output/file.out.index does not exist**
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:930)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:631)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:950)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.openFSDataInputStream(SecureIOUtils.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.copyMapOutput(LocalFetcher.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.doCopy(LocalFetcher.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.run(LocalFetcher.java:86)
**2019-11-19 14:49:14,357 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1214244919_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA**
2019-11-19 14:49:14,372 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 18
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=840
                FILE: Number of bytes written=991668
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=2
                Map output records=8
                Map output bytes=82
                Map output materialized bytes=85
                Input split bytes=204
                Combine input records=8
                Combine output records=6
                Spilled Records=6
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=0
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=577241088
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=48
```

(I highlighted the parts I consider important with **)

I'm running the [introduction source code](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Source_Code) of Hadoop.

- The folder for which the file is missing exists.
- I deleted the entire tmp folder -> didn't help.
- I tried [MapReduce doesn't produce an output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836908/mapreduce-doesnt-produce-an-output) but there was no such entry. Adding one didn't help either.

Comment: I don't like that you have some weird characters in your file path, also Hadoop isn't formally supported in Windows. Whilst you should be able to get this to work somehow, it's much better to run a Docker container/VM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Hadoop, and your code, as a user without spaces in the name (not `king lui`)

One way to test this scenario is

```
set HADOOP_USER_NAME=myuser 
yarn jar your-app.jar
```

Then it might error saying that /user/myuser doesn't exist, but you can create that directory

Answer (score 0):

Changing the username worked to a username without spaces worked.

I tried this before trying `set HADOOP_USER_NAME=myuser`, so I don't know if this helps.